# error: ambiguates old declaration ‘double round(double)’

Tags: c++

> ```
> /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:311:1: error: ambiguates old declaration ‘double round(double)’
> g.cpp: In function ‘int round(double)’:
> g.cpp:14:24: error: new declaration ‘int round(double)’
> /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:311:1: error: ambiguates old declaration ‘double round(double)’
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int round(double number);

int main()
{
    double number = 5.9;
    round(number);
    return 0;
}
int round(double number)
{
    return static_cast<int>(floor(number + 0.5));
}
```

Why is my compiler showing an error

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory... there's apparently already a function which cannot be distinguished from your `int round(double)`.

Answer (score 13):

The error is pretty explicit here. The `<cmath>` header is already introducing a function `double round(double)` and you can't overload based on return type. Yes, it's defined in the `std` namespace but you are doing `using namespace std;` (it's also implementation defined whether it is first defined in the global namespace before it is injected into `std`). To e completely portable, you'll need to give your function a different name or stick it in another namespace - or, of course, use the `round` function that `<cmath>` gives you. But get rid of that `using namespace std;` too.